# What is correct: "both sides of you" or "both sides of yours"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

Which is right?

> - both sides of you
> - both sides of yours

Example:

> I know both sides of you(rs) and they make you the girl I love.

Comment: Depends on context.  Probably you are talking about "sides" of somebody like "good side" and "bad side" and you want "I know both sides of you".  But suppose there was a potluck and she brought potato salad and deviled eggs- two of your absolute favorites.  You might very well say to her, "I know both "sides" of yours and they make you the girl I love." ;-)

Comment: I actually wanted to express the first one meaning you mentioned but I used the second form ('of yours'). Feel bad now because I used it wrong, oh well. I was hoping they both are correct. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

They both seem right to me. If you have two sides, then there are "two sides of you" or "both sides of you". And both of those sides belong to you, so they are "both sides of yours".